# laravel 5.5 use model in command

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm a newbie in Laravel5.5, and want to use model in my command ,
first php artisan make:model MyTest,  then I use model to get data from mysql.
the command file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Model\MyTest;

class UboxDataAnalysis extends Command
{
    //...

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->line('Then start query');
        $o = new App\Model\MyTest();
    }
}
```

And the Model file is:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use DB;

class MyTest extends Model
{
    //
    function get_data(){
        $uboxTest = DB::connection('mysql-test');
        $res = $uboxTest::table('m_user')->where('user_id',166);
        var_dump($res);
    }
}
```

But the CLI output is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]    
Class 'App\Console\Commands\App\Model\MyTest' not found
```

And I googled and find something about [laravel5.5 doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models).
`To get started, let's create an Eloquent model. Models typically live in the app directory, but you are free to place them anywhere that can be auto-loaded according to your composer.json file.`
Is that to say, I need add some config in the composer.json?
Can anybody give me some advice? Thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already imported the class with `use App\Model\MyTest;`, so you can just write `$o = new MyTest();`.
Instead of that you could remove the import statement and write `$o = new \App\Model\MyTest();` (note the added backslash).

Comment: Oh, I see, so I haven't good understand the **namespace**, then I will go to read the content of **php namespace** again.